# Content security policy error

Tags: apex, visualforce, google-map

I developed a Visualforce page with an integration that visualizes a Google Map, but when the page is opened, in the console browser I can see the errors:

> ```
> -Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'reflected-xss'.
> -Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"
> -Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'referrer'.
> ```

What is causing this message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are harmless messages, caused by deprecated CSP directives ('reflected-css' and 'referrer'), as well as an anti-spoofing message ('Refused to set unsafe header'). None of these three messages impact script functionality or resource acquisition. If you're having a problem with your code, these messages are not the cause. You can search your favorite search engine for more details on these messages.

Answer (score 0):

The reflected-xss support was removed from Chrome
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=657737&can=1&q=reflected-xss&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Comment: Can **[edit]** your answer to add some detail about how this change is relevant to the question?